# fetch value from table_2 when there is no data in table_1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables , 
`table_t1` and `table_t2`.

First I have to look in `table_t1` and fetch data from it, but there is no data found in `table_t1`, then I have to fetch data from `table_t2`.

***Note***: fetch data from `table_t2` only if there is no data found in `table_t1`.

I have tried to make a query for this, but unfortunately not succeeded, its too far from working.

Can you guys please help me do it?

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help.

Comment: Also, please post the code you tried so far and the problems you are having with it

Comment: I think you're going to need dynamic SQL for this, i.e. you can't do this from an ordinary query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I didn't say anything yesterday, but this is the second time in two days you express an opinion that something can only be done with dynamic SQL. Since in both cases that wasn't actually so, perhaps you can refrain from offering it? Of course you were absolutely clear in both cases it was just an opinion; but you are a veteran on the site, and your opinion carries (for good reason) a lot of weight. Thanks!

Comment: @mathguy The answer given by Dudu, which is very clever, would only work if the two tables have the same structure, or at least the same number of columns with the same types.  If you can think of a way to answer here in general without using dynamic SQL then please let us know.

Comment: By the way, I'm no veteran.  You're thinking of Gordon Linoff :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Nothing wrong about Gordon (he has provided enormous help to a lot of people), but he makes mistakes quite often; I don't think he'd be in the top 10 of the most trusted respondents. (And, rest assured, I let him know when he is not doing things the right way.) And, by the way, I expect the courtesy to be returned - others should call me out when they think I'm out of bounds.   Cheers!

Comment: Also, one would hope in this kind of problem the two tables have the same structure (or if they don't, the SELECT is not SELECT *, but lists of columns that have not only the same number and data type, but also the same semantics in both tables).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, any 2 tables can be connected by a UNION ALL operator, no matter what their structure is :-) e.g. - `select t.*,f.* from sys.ts$ t left join sys.file$ f on 1=2 union all select t.*,f.* from sys.file$ f left join sys.ts$ t on 1=2 `

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz AFAIK Both the column types _and_ number of columns must be the same for many RDBMS.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you overlooked the example I gave. You can replace `sys.ts$` and `sys.files$` with any 2 other tables.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - you wouldn't call that a "union" of the two tables though, would you? (It is, in fact, a "disjoint union" or "direct sum" of the two sets in set theory - but even there a "disjoint union" is not the same as "union".)

Comment: **1)** UNION ALL is outer to the set theory **2)** This is offcourse an edge case but it demonsrate very well that the source tables do not have to be identical in order to be used with UNION ALL operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both tables are in the same structure.
If it is not the case, replace the `*` with matching columns/expressions.

```
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2 where not exists (select null from t1)
```

---

I ran some tests on Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, focusing on the 2nd part of the UNION ALL.
Although the execution plan indicates a full table scan for both t1 and t2, it is clear according to the query metrics, **none of them is being fully scanned**

Comment: In case the data exists in both tables (OP has not clarified as far as I can tell) a `union` instead of `union all` would work.

Comment: While it is true that `t1` will not be fully scanned for each row of `t2` in the second branch of `union all` (there were a couple of comments about this, which were good for the community to see - not sure why they were deleted), because the optimizer is smart enough to figure that out, the optimizer is STILL not smart enough to avoid the second branch altogether. It will STILL do a full scan of `t2`. So, if `t2` is a very large table, it may still be better to solve the problem programmatically (in a procedure) - one of the few cases when pure SQL may not be the best choice.

Comment: @AkioHamasaki, Nope. **(1)** OP was clear. t1 is being fetched first and only if it has no data we would fetch from t2. **(2)** **UNION** will remove duplicates within t1 or within t2 which was not defined as a desired results.

Comment: @AkioHamasaki - besides, in general one would choose `union all` over `union` unless there was a very good reason to do otherwise, since `union` is much slower - precisely because it removes duplicates, even when one branch is empty.

Comment: @mathguy,  t2 is not being fully scanned. This seems like a very straight forward use-case for an optimizer to handle. Since this is not a correlated query there is no reason to touch t2 before validating the NOT EXISTS predicate.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tested before I wrote what I wrote. Table `t2` IS fully scanned. Try this for yourself and look at the explain plan - `select deptno from scott.dept
union all
select deptno from scott.emp where not exists (select null from scott.dept);`  You will see the second branch of UNION ALL does a full table scan of EMP.

Comment: Just do me the small favor and run the Explain Plan on the query I pasted in my Comment. You will see the Full Table Scan right there, and then you'll have to explain why what you said is contradicted by the Explain Plan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127399/discussion-between-mathguy-and-dudu-markovitz).

Comment: @mathguy. I think I was very clear - "Although the execution plan indicates a full table scan for both t1 and t2, it is clear that none of them is being fully scanned"

Comment: That doesn't even make sense - at compile time, when the optimizer works, it doesn't know if the first table will be empty or not. Which suggests one should look at the EXECUTE plan to see what Oracle actually does - and it STILL shows full table scan of the second table even when the first table is not empty. Just run the plans for yourself before you respond, please.

Comment: @mathguy, execution plans are my bread and butter :-) what you are missing here is that database providers do not always expose their optimizations in the execution plans. In this case the full table scan of t2 is actually conditional and the full table scan of t1 is actually optimized to stop after the first row found.

Comment: @mathguy, and I did wrote very clearly - "Although the execution plan indicates a full table scan for both t1 and t2...", so there is no debate here about the execution plan.

Comment: I stand corrected. I just ran a test. I created a table `t1` with 100 rows and another one, `t2`, with 100 million rows. `select count(*) from t2` takes over 4 seconds, but `select count(*) from ( select id from t1 union all select id from t2 where not exists (select null from t1))` is instantaneous (with `clear buffer cache` in between just to make sure any reading would be done from disk). So, indeed, `t2` is not read, despite the execution plan saying it is. Good to know!